# finding the average after a BubbleSort Method

Tags: integer, average

I am an IT students, and i really need to finish writing this code, i am almost done with it, its sorting the numbers using Bubble sort but the things is, that we have to find the mean at the end, and i have no idea how to do this. can anybody help me? 
my code looks like this, and till here it also works, I just need to add the rest to it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, i, j;
    double temp;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of Numbers you want to sort:");
    num = input.nextInt();

    double array[] = new double[num];

    System.out.println("Enter " + num + " Number: ");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        array[i] = input.nextDouble();

    for (i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted list:");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

}

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to edit a bit. Just add a variable average to your program , int variable if you need an integer average or float if you need a precise result (as I follow in below code). Sum all the elements to a variable sum (integer element) and then divide it by total number of elements ( basic math!!!). That's it, print it and you are done.

your program should look like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int num, i, j, sum=0;
float avg=0;
double temp;
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the amount of Numbers you want to sort:");
num = input.nextInt();

double array[] = new double[num];

System.out.println("Enter " + num + " Number: ");

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();

for (i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Sorted list:");

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    System.out.println(array[i]);

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
 sum = sum+array[i];
avg=sum/num;
System.out.println("Average : "+avg);
 }
}
```

Comment: dividing by `num`every iteration will not give you the average. The for-loop will give you `num` results and `num` outputs. This line has to be outside your loop.

Comment: @Thomas I wont believe if you tell me you are software engineer!! Don't you know in java if there is no curly braces after `for` statement only one line following it will be executed and also It is not mandatory to use curly braces after 'for'. So `sum=sum+array[i]` is gonna execute `num` times after that only it goes to avg=sum/num. You should study some basics. Reference :  java complete reference by herbert schildit seventh edition page 89 para 2.

Comment: @Billa Thank you so much, the code worked. you are a life saver :)

Comment: @BarinMangal I am happy to hear it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int avg = 0;   
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     avg = avg + array[i];
 }
 avg = avg / array.length();
```

Comment: `int avg = 0;` and there is no `count()` method on a plain `double[]`.